# can not show input method pane in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

I have created a simple `UIViewController`, and set a `UIWebView` as a default view.

When I inserted it into a `NavigationController`, it did not show input method anymore if I click in some text field in page.

Any ideas?

input method = soft keypad,

ps: i set the simple UIViewController as rootViewController of MainWindow, also take no effect. can not show soft keypad too.

Comment: What do you mean by `input method`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I just encountered this. For me, the keyboard is apparently sitting behind my web view. I happened to rotate the device (in the simulator) and noticed, during the screen rotation drawing process, that I could see parts of the keyboard behind my webview.* ***[Quoted]*** [1]

*Interestingly, I can't seem to reproduce this problem in a freshly created sample application - yet I can't see what the problem can be with my view hierarchy.* ***[Quoted]*** [2]

[1][2]: [Reference](https://discussions.apple.com/message/7735443?messageID=7735443)

---

```
Is your web view in a modal view controller?
```

Comment: create project "BrowserTest"; delete *.xib/*.m/*.h(not include supporting file);
add a window named "MainWindow";
NewFile >> Cocoa Touch >> UIViewController subclass >> add a class Named "BrowserView" with xib file .

replace default view in BrowerView.xib with a WebView,   connect it to view of files's owner;

add a line into viewDidLoad method in BrowserView.m, make view load some url;

add a ViewController into MainWindow.xib and set it class to BrowserView for reference to BrowserView.xib;

set Window's rootViewController to the referenced ViewController;

then build and run, then problem;

Comment: @Ron: Sorry I am not on my Mac but i will do that once i get my office, but i can assure you that if you create a new project **Dont modify anything** and simply add UIWebView to the `MainWindow` everything will work just fine.

Comment: yeap, i found the problem i have.. when delete all the source code , i have to add a new "Application" as the applicaiton main entry instead of Window. when i do so, problem is deal; whatever, thank u.

Comment: @Ron: I am glad that i could be a part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check if the `userInteraction` is enabled for the web view. If not you can set it by

```
yourWebview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: i checked in my Interface build, it selected  UserInteraction Enabled defaultly, and, i also add ur code in method -(void)viewDidLoad.  but no effect.

Comment: create project "BrowserTest"; delete *.xib/*.m/*.h(not include supporting file);
add a window named "MainWindow";
NewFile >> Cocoa Touch >> UIViewController subclass >> add a class Named "BrowserView" with xib file .

replace default view in BrowerView.xib with a WebView,   connect it to view of files's owner;

add a line into viewDidLoad method in BrowserView.m, make view load some url;

add a ViewController into MainWindow.xib and set it class to BrowserView for reference to BrowserView.xib;

set Window's rootViewController to the referenced ViewController;

then build and run, then problem;

Comment: yeap, i found the problem i have.. when delete all the source code , i have to add a new "Application" as the applicaiton main entry instead of Window. when i do so, problem is deal; whatever, thank u.